# Remove a value in an array and decrease the size of it

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an array filled with some values. After running this code:

```
array = zeros(10)

for i in 1:10
   array[i] = 2*i + 3
end
```

The array looks like:

```
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
  5.0
  7.0
  9.0
 11.0
 13.0
 15.0
 17.0
 19.0
 21.0
 23.0
```

I would like to obtain, for example, the following array by removing the third value:

```
9-element Array{Float64,1}:
      5.0
      7.0
     11.0
     13.0
     15.0
     17.0
     19.0
     21.0
     23.0
```

How to do that?

**EDIT**

If I have an array (and not a vector), like here:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]

1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5
```

The `deleteat!` proposed is not working:

```
a = deleteat!([1 2 3 4 5], 1)

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching deleteat!(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Int64)

You might have used a 2d row vector where a 1d column vector was required.
Note the difference between 1d column vector [1,2,3] and 2d row vector [1 2 3].
You can convert to a column vector with the vec() function.
Closest candidates are:
  deleteat!(::Array{T,1} where T, ::Integer) at array.jl:875
  deleteat!(::Array{T,1} where T, ::Any) at array.jl:913
  deleteat!(::BitArray{1}, ::Integer) at bitarray.jl:961
```

I don't want a column vector. I would want:

```
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  3  4  5
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: use `deleteat!` to modify the passed array.

Comment: Thank you, it works for a vector. How to do with the value in an array ?

Comment: please give an example what you want because you might mean different things here (or asking to perform a logically impossible operation).

Comment: I just edited my question in this way

Comment: Now that I wrote my answer, I'm not sure anymore if I got you right: are you confused between `Vector{T}`, `Array{T, 1}`, and `Array{T, 2}`, or do you explicitely want to delete from a n-times-1 `Array{T, 2}`?

Comment: For `Matrix` you do not have `deleteat!`. With `x = [1 2 3 4 5]` you can make a copy `x[:, [1:2;4:5]]` or use a view to avoid copying of data and `y=view(x, :, [1:2;4:5])`.

Comment: @phg , My goal is not to delete an `array{T, 2}` but reduce it (exactly, delete the 0 in it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make that clear: `Vector{T}` in Julia is just a synonym for `Array{T, 1}`, unless you're talking about something else... we call `Array`s of all ranks arrays.

But this seems to be a Matlab-inherited misconception.  In Julia, you construct a `Matrix{T}`, ie., an `Array{T, 2}`, by using spaces in the literal:

```
julia> a = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5
```

Deleting from a matrix does not make sense in general, since you can't trivially "fix the shape" in a rectangular layout.

A `Vector` or `Array{T, 1}` can be written using commas:

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

And on this, `deleteat!` works:

```
julia> deleteat!(a, 1)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

For completeness, there's also a third variant, the `RowVector`, which results of a transposition:

```
julia> a'
1×4 RowVector{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 2  3  4  5
```

From this you also can't delete.

Answer (score 1):

Deleteat! is only defined for:

Fully implemented by:

```
Vector (a.k.a. 1-dimensional Array)
BitVector (a.k.a. 1-dimensional BitArray)
```

A Row Vector (2 Dimensions) won't work. 
But ... there is a workaround by this trick:

```
julia> deleteat!(a[1,:], 1)'   # mind the ' -> transposes it back to a row vector. 

1×4 RowVector{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 2  3  4  5
```

Ofcourse this wouldn't work for an Array with 2 or more rows.

Comment: Please use better [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). That makes things easier to read.